A man hires someone to murders his wife, but she kills the attacker in self-defense. What crime has the husband committed?
Just today I watched a movie. A husband wants his wife dead and hires a killer. She manages to kill her attacker in self defence but the police and a jury don’t believe her and she is convicted for murder. The husband knows she is innocent but keeps quiet. Eventually he is caught. What crimes has he committed? In the USA, or in other jurisdictions? Is it murder even though he didn’t kill anyone himself?

What crimes has he committed? Are you asking about him hiring a hitman, or are you asking about him allowing his wife to be wrongfully convicted?  Or both?

It might be nice to remove the title of the movie.  It adds a spoiler, and is unnecessary for the question.

Except for some details (the hitman's death, relation among the players), this sounds  similar to the Florida case of the Adelson family for the murder of Dan Markel in which the family hired a hitman to murder Dan on behalf of Wendy Adelson. Charlie (Wendy's brother) was convicted and sentenced to life in prison for first degree murder and other related charges for being the mastermind. Their mother Donna Adelson goes on trial later this year.

canada
He has committed attempted murder of his wife, via "counselling" (Criminal Code, s. 22):

Where a person counsels another person to be a party to an offence and that other person is afterwards a party to that offence, the person who counselled is a party to that offence ...


Possibly also conspiracy? 465(1)(a)

Since a felony was committed and a death occurred, could this be felony murder in some states??

germany Anstiftung zum Versuchten Mord (of the wife)
Hiring a Killer is the textbook example of Anstiftung (Incitement) for Mord (murder). Since the would-be-killer did not succeed, it stayed at the Versuch (attempt), so it's Incitement for Attempted Murder.

Incitement under StGB §26 says, that the inciter is to be punished as the actor would.
Attempt under StGB §23 says, that the attempt is punished just like a successful crime.
Mord (murder 1st degree) under StGB §211 says the mandatory punishment is a life sentence.

Thus, the Husband is facing a mandatory life sentence, as I see no factors to give the possible leniency under StGB §23.

§23 only says that the attempt is punishable as well, it doesn't say that it bears the same penalty as the successful crime. In particular $23 (2) says that if the attempt is unsuccessful, the penalty can be reduced.

@PMF the wording is can be punished more leniently, which means that in inverse, by default the punishment equal. In practice, leniency isn't given for attempted murder, especially not if you incited.

The Hitchcock movie was set in London, but the remake was set in New York, so I will focus on that.
New York State Penal Code, Section 125.25: A person is guilty of murder in the second degree when [...with] intent to cause the death of another person, he causes the death of such person or of a third person
Clearly, that it was Tony (Steven in the remake) was trying to do.
New York State Penal Code, Section 110.05 makes attempting to commit a crime... a crime.
There is also Solicitation (Tony/Steven asked Charles/David to commit a crime) and Conspiracy (the two agreed to commit the crime and there was an overt act in furtherance of that crime), but I believe those charges would be subsumed by the Attempt charge, which as a Class B felony, could result in up to 25 years in prison.
Edit:
Someone does actually die during the crime, just not the intended victim.  That might make Steven guilty of either the original murder (since there is a “or of a third person” clause) or of “felony murder” (a homicide during the course of another felony), but I don’t think so.  New York Penal Law 125.25(3), which describes felony murder in detail, specifically excludes the death of another participant.  It also, however, excludes murder as a predicate felony, presumably because it is included directly under the definition of murder.  I believe that the death of a co-conspirator in a murder would not automatically be considered a murder, the way the death of a bystander would be, but I could be wrong.

Isn't there also obstruction of justice since he is dishonest with the police about the dead man and the dead man's purpose in the house, as well as the fact that he knows that his wife is innocent but allows her to be sentenced to death for want of supporting testimony ? If such false statements made to police were repeated in the course of the trial he would of course be guilty of perjury. Also conspiracy to steal, e.g. from wife's inheritance and/or life insurance company in the event of a successful murder by accomplice. Possible "wire fraud" too.

@Trunk — I don’t remember the dialog well enough to remember if he outright lies to the police, but yeah.

Add all the offence sentences together consecutively and he'll be away for along time.

@Trunk — well, you cannot always add them...

If one intends to cause the death of N people, but causes the death of a different number M of people, would the person be charged with N counts of murder, or M, or whichever was greater, or what?  Would the state have to associate particular intended victims with particular decedents, such that if e.g. the jury finds it plausible that particular decedent might have died of a heart attack prior before the arrival of the defendant, the defendant would be not guilty of the murder of the associated intended victim, or what fact patterns would be required?

@supercat — I think it’s gotta be M.  You cannot always calculate N.  My question is, should M include any accomplices who get got?

In Belarus, he would have been slapped with 3 articles and his wife would have gone. For the husband, a contract killing and 139ch1 murder through Art. 14, 14 is not a completed action. In the СНГ, you can forget about such an article as self-defense.

Hello, and welcome! I suspect that your answer would be fine in whatever language you usually write in; as a native English speaker reading it in English, it's confusing. I'm guessing three articles means three criminal offenses? Wht do you men the wife would have "gone"? Just that none of the circumstances would change the wife's status (since it sounds like self-defense isn't a thing there)? What is the CHI (my apologies if this something that everyone else would know). I suspect that sort of thing is the reason for the downvotes.

Do you mean that the "wife would have walked", would not have been imprisoned?
СНГ (Содружество Независимых Государств) is CIS in English, Confederation of Independent States.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
